# Bypass Login of a JSP page

Tags: jsp, autologin

I have a Link which requires authentication to open it The authentication page is in JSP on the Server Want to bypass that page or autocomplete it automatically so to redirect to the link directly.
The Authentication page consists of 2 fields username and password and a button Login.
Is there any way i can bypass this
I cant use Cookies since i dont want the user to enter the details.Something which hardcode the page

Comment: Plz explain little more.

Comment: Just need to bypass an JSP authentication page via script,etc.Its fields should get automatically filled and the button should be clicked automatically.and the user should directly be redirected to the targetted page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to write a servlet filter with all the logic yourself or use a full fledged security framework like [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). For your simple use case using a framework would probably a overkill There are many tutorials on how to use servlet filter for security purpose. You can refer to [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial) or [this](http://gardiary.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/the-most-basic-securing-web-application-with-servlet-filter/) tutorial if you want to create your own filter

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Is there any other simple way?Can screen scraping work where i can directly input the values and redirect the page?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case ?

Comment: My page resides on server(localhost tomcat).there is another page named login.jsp which provides authentication.In order to access my page i need authentication which i want to bypass/hardcode the values.The authentication page cannot be removed.so i need a mechanism by which i can enter the values directly and redirect automatically

Comment: Hardcoding would be very bad in terms of security. You might need sen d some  token value  in GET/POST request and then your login mechanism can check if it exists then login should be bypassed.